# Selecting few columns in Google Sheet's QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am trying to select few columns in Google Sheet's QUERY function but get errors when I combine with other formula in the function.

Here is my formula. What I am trying to do? my goal is combine data (column) from different sheets that will ultimately feed into a pivot table

> `=QUERY({TeamData!C:C,TeamBonusData!F:F;IndividualData!M:O,IndividualBonusData!P:R},)` - this does not work

> `=QUERY({TeamData!C:C,TeamData!F:F},)` - this works.

Comment: Hi and welcome. When declaring an array, **commas** separate columns, and **semicolons** separate rows [Doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en). But your query combines columns and rows (commas and semicolons) in a single array. Would you please explain EXACTLY the outcome you are trying to achieve in the failed array `{TeamData!C:C,TeamBonusData!F:F;IndividualData!M:O,IndividualBonusData!P:R}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the advice Tedinoz gave and ensure that those references have a matching number of rows and columns. It may help if you visually group ranges so that they stack side-by-side or on top of each other, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  teams, teamsBonus, individuals, individualsBonus, 
  lambda( 
    numTeams, numIndividuals, 
    {
      array_constrain(teams, numTeams, 2), array_constrain(teamsBonus, numTeams, 2); 
      array_constrain(individuals, numIndividuals, 2), array_constrain(individualsBonus, numIndividuals, 2) 
    }
  )(
    min(rows(teams), rows(teamsBonus)), 
    min(rows(individuals), rows(individualsBonus)) 
  ) 
)( 
  TeamData!C2:D, TeamBonusData!F2:G, IndividualData!M2:O, IndividualBonusData!P2:R 
)
```